# Overflow:hidden full width div doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I have a simple problem with a menu, its a 2 part menu : on the left, a traditional UL. On the right, a link contained in a div.
The right div has fixed width. The left div must take all remaining space.

I tried the overflow:hidden technique, to no avail
https://coderwall.com/p/0ph8lg/overflow-hidden-trick-to-fill-remaining-width

https://jsfiddle.net/3gfqyux4/

```
.container {
    width:800px;
    height:50px;
}

.left-menu {
    background-color:red;
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left-menu ul li {
    display:inline;
}
.right-menu {
    background-color:blue;
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: "The overflow:hidden technique"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change an order of this two lists ;)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right-menu">
    <a href="xyz.com">
        xyz.com
    </a>
</div>    
<div class="left-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>menu</li>
         <li>menu</li>
         <li>menu</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gfqyux4/2/

Comment: actually it was as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Use `calc`

```
.container {
   width:800px;
   height:50px;
}

.left-menu {
    background-color:red;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}

.left-menu ul li {
    display:inline;
 }

.right-menu {
     background-color:blue;
     width:calc(100% - 150px);
     height:50px;
 }
```

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3gfqyux4/3/

Comment: never thought of using calc, thanks for your answer although I just had to inverse the order of my divs

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean your "right" div has a fixed width (as indicated in your code) and that the left div should take up the remaining width.

`flexbox` can do that.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.left-menu {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.left-menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.right-menu {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 1 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>menu</li>
      <li>menu</li>
      <li>menu</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-menu">
    <a href="xyz.com">
            xyz.com
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4sn2ob2w/2/)

[**CSS-Tricks: Complete Guide**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't change the order: remember **display:inline-block**;

```
.container {
    width:800px;
    height:50px;
}

.left-menu {
    background-color:red;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    height:50px;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    display:inline-block;

}
.left-menu ul li {
    display:inline;
}
.right-menu {
    background-color:blue;
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```